# Using QFileDialog with QWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog, qwindow

I try to implement an application with OpenGL,
so as the following example suggested, I used an QWindow to create an OpenGL context.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html

In this application, I want to create a file dialog when I press S key.
However, `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName` requires a parent of `QWidget`.
[The documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName) says if `parent` is 0, the dialog will be shown centered over the parent widget.
I wonder in this case 
it is ok to simply use `nullptr` as `parent`.

Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QtGui/QWindow>

class DisplayWindow final : public QWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DisplayWindow(QWindow* parent = 0)
        : QWindow(parent)
    {
        // Setup OpenGL context
        // ...
    }

protected:
    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) override
    {
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key_S)
        {
            //                                          ???????
            QString path = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(nullptr, "Save", "", "");
            qDebug() << path;
        }
    }

};

class MainWindow final : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        displayWindow = new DisplayWindow;
        auto* container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(displayWindow, this);
        container->setMinimumSize(200, 200);
        setCentralWidget(container);
    }

private:
    DisplayWindow* displayWindow;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "moc_test.cpp"
```

Comment: I don't get the point of your question. The doc says you can do it, you can try and see for yourself, but you still ask a question here.

Comment: @undu The point is the difference in type. The type of the parent of DisplayWindow is QWindow but QFileDialog::getSaveFileName requires QWidget. I wonder in such a case it is valid to use nullptr as the doc says.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it should be safe. Since you do not dynamically allocate memory you don't have to delete anything. If you set up parents, Qt will delete the widgets on its own. 
In here it just has affects on the window modality and position. 
If you want to set a parent, you could just use "this" in your context.